# MYSQL query for selecting the result of a condition of one table and showing it on another table

Tags: mysql

How to substract(or add) one row from the previous row of one table(stock_details)..  and showing the result in another table(item_details)..??

```
 1st table:stock_details
----------+----------+-----------
 stock_name | quantity | type  
------------+----------+----------
 laddu      |   200    | PURCHASE         
  Ghee      |    50    |  ISSUE        


2nd table:item_details
----------+----------
stock_name | quantity   
------------+---------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- INSERT INTO item_details
--  or
-- CREATE TABLE item_details
SELECT   stock_name, SUM(CASE type
           WHEN 'PURCHASE' THEN +quantity
           WHEN 'ISSUE'    THEN -quantity
         END) AS quantity
FROM     stock_details
GROUP BY stock_name
```