# mysql query for selecting the result from one table and inserting in another table

Tags: mysql

sir..can u plz tell me the query for this plz

table1

```
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|type
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  32    |purchase
rice      |shiva |  10    |issue
wheat     |ganesh|  50    | purchase
wheat     |ganesh|  45    | issue   
ghee      |ganesh|  50    | purchase
ghee      |ganesh|   5    | issue
```

expected output in table2

```
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  22    |
wheat     |ganesh|  5     | 
ghee      |ganesh|  45    |
```

Comment: Please stop asking the same sh*t over and over again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643157/mysql-query-for-selecting-the-result-of-a-condition-of-one-table-and-showing-it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632592/mysql-query-for-selecting-the-result-of-a-condition-of-one-table-and-showing-it

Comment: jw gave you right answer on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643157/mysql-query-for-selecting-the-result-of-a-condition-of-one-table-and-showing-it . Only in his sql fiddle you need to change varchar length to you need.

Answer (score 3):

And here the same answer like in every other question that you posted

```
INSERT INTO secondTable (stock_name,temple,quantity)
SELECT  stock_name,
        temple,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'purchase' 
                     THEN quantity 
                     ELSE quantity * -1 
                 END) quantity
FROM    firstTable
GROUP   BY stock_name, temple
```